# Why do Americans say "Nice to meet you" just when they meet someone? Shouldn't it be said when ending the conversation?

Tags: american-english, british-english

In movies and TV series, I have heard Americans saying "Nice to meet you" when they meet someone. This is really weird; why would you say that in the beginning and not when ending the conversation? You barely know that person at the time.

Comment: Formality wise?  I'm sure it's not just specific to Americans.

Comment: because 'to meet', in this context, means to come into the presence and/or be introduced to someone... once we've fulfilled that, we've met the person. I don't have to know anything about that person

Comment: It's the land of _Hope_ ....

Comment: You might also say "It was nice to meet you" when ending a conversation with a new acquaintance.

Comment: "I **was** nice meeting you" at the end of the conversation.

Comment: "Pleased to meet you, won't you guess my name?" Don't the Rolling Stones do this too?

Comment: no, because you meet someone as soon as you introduce yourself (or are introduced) to them

Answer (score 1):

If the phrase used started with *it is* or *it was*, then when it was said would make a difference. But since the exact phrase "*nice to meet you*" does not include a verbal tense, it can be said at either the start or the end of a conversation.

### At the *start* of a conversation

> - ✔ <sup>It ***is***</sup> nice to meet you.
>   Whether the meeting is thought to be a 5-second greeting and handshake or an extended conversation, its still in the immediate present or just-completed past, so *is* is fine.
> - ✘ <sup>It ***was***</sup> nice to meet you.
>   Even if *meet* is considered to be that 5-second greeting and handshake which has just finished, the past tense would be odd at this point.

### At the *end* of a conversation

> - ✘ <sup>It ***is***</sup> nice to meet you.
>   Nobody would normally say this at the end of a conversation. However, it's still less strange than saying *it was* as the start of a conversation.
> - ✔ <sup>It ***was***</sup> nice to meet you.
>   This is perfectly normal at the end of a conversation.

---

Without either *it is* or *it was*, "*nice to meet you*" can be said at either the start or the end of a conversation (assuming that the person being talked to has been met for the first time) and be meaningful at either time. In fact, it could be said at *both* times—for instance, once after shaking hands, and again when waving goodbye.

Comment: +1 Exactly right.

Answer (score -1):

One answer could be that English (all languages I imagine) are full of stock phrases that do not necessarily make literal sense.

But it is presumably a statement that you anticipate it being a pleasant and mutually satisfactory encounter, so you are pleased that (it is nice that) it is taking place. It is to a agree a compliment to the other party.

If people didn't shorten the stock phrase it would be clearer that there is a difference between:

> "It is nice to meet you" (present)

and

> "It was nice to have met you" (past perfect)

It would sound more British English to say:

> "It is lovely to make your acquaintance"

as "nice" is rather deprecated and "acquaintance" more specifically flags up that you didn't know them before (and is a little standoffish I suppose). On the other hand when parting it is probably appropriate to switch to

> "It was lovely to have met you"

unles you really are trying to be standoffish. And English English is less formal that it used to be anyway.

Comment: how is 'nice to meet you' being used in an unliteral sense when one definition of to meet is to be introduced to someone (for the first time). John, this is Matt. Matt, this is John. Matt and John have now met

Comment: It isn't - but the OP suggested that it didn't make sense as it should be said at the end of the convesation. 

If indeed it didn't make sense, it could still be the stock thing to say and be understood accordingly.

That's all I meant.